# Google Fonts не отвечает, в чем проблема?

Tags: html, css3

Стандартная ситуация: только что все работало, <бах!> и ничего не работает. 
Есть страница, к ней подключается через CSS шрифт от гугла:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,500);
```

В консоли вываливается ошибка:

```
GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/DXI1ORHCp... ::ERR_FAILED
```

При переходе по сгенерированной ссылке также выдает 404.
Подскажите что делаю не так?
Спасибо!

Comment: У меня последнее время аналогичная проблема, подозреваю, что у гугла произошел какой-то рассинхрон серверов со статикой.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема на серверах Google, кириллические шрифты и возможно некоторые другие у Opensans возвращают 404.

Здесь уже обсуждают
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665542/google-fonts-loading-returns-404-in-chrome/29667528#29667528